# iPhone spatial search

Tags: iphone, geospatial

I want to write an iPhone app, that will need to do a distance based search (eg. find results within 100km)

I'm not concerned about what storage technology is used, as long as it is stored on the device

Comment: Some of the code out there for doing this starts be determining a box whose sides are the search distance (miles/KM) with starting location centered in that square region, this gives you something to narrow down results from the database, then each db result is checked against the center point and chosen radius to give you just those points in the target radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a question a while back intending to build a similar application.  I found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782639/geospatial-library-for-the-iphone) helpful.  I believe what you want to do can be largely accomplished by using `CLLocation`'s `getDistanceFrom:` method.

Comment: Given the database only has about 5000 points this is working fast enough, before I've even done some simple boxing in SQL

Answer (score 2):

Although I have never used it, there is a spatial derivative of SQLLiteDB that you could compile and use in your app - then you could issue spatial queries against that database.  It's something I have mulled over but never had the chance to try:

http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking exactly? What do you need to find?

For a generic case I would maybe use the long/lat coords on the "items" to make a quad-tree and use that to speed up the search.